# ActiveRecord: Access join table attribute through association using delegate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a `Post` model in my app, which has a `posts` attribute that stores a JSON object that looks something like this:

```
Post.last.posts = {
    twitter: 'This is a tweet',
    facebook: 'This is a facebook post'
}
```

A user creates a single `Post`, which is then sent out to multiple platforms. This architecture made sense for the original app design. Now I want to offer the user the ability to hide a post they've made to one platform without affecting posts to other platforms. Because a post is a single model in the database I need to find a workaround. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but I decided to create a join table between my `User` model and `Post` model. Note that posts are created by a different user model (`Admin`) and `User` merely views posts.

Here are my models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :post_users
    has_many :users, through: :post_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :post_users
    has_many :posts, through: :post_users
end

class PostUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
    delegate :hide_twitter, to: :post
    delegate :hide_facebook, to: :post

    def hide_twitter
        self.hide_twitter
    end
end
```

In the view I'm building, each `Post` is represented as a series of cards - one for each platform. So if a post is on Twitter and Facebook, it will be shown as two seperate cards - one per platform. What I want to do is give `User` the ability to hide one of the cards without affecting the other(s). Because a `Post` belongs to many users, this has to be an attribute of a join table (e.g. `PostUser`).

What I'd like to know is if it's possible to access this attribute of the join table through the `Post` model?  I want to do something like the following but I'm not sure if it's possible or if I'm taking the correct approach by using `delegate` in my join table.

```
current_user.posts.first.hide_twitter
=> false
current_user.posts.first.hide_facebook
=> true
```

When I use `delegate` as above and try to call the above line of code, I get the following error:

```
Post Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "post_users" ON "posts"."id" = "post_users"."post_id" WHERE "post_users"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 90]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `hide_twitter' for #<Post:0x007fc27d383f50>
from /Users/ACIDSTEALTH/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.5.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
```

I realize I could do something very roundabout like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4284343/4139179), but was hoping for something a little more elegant/conventional.

Comment: How do you define `hide_twitter` and `hide_facebook` in your `Post` model?

Comment: It's not defined in my `Post` model currently. I'm not sure I'm using `delegate` right here. I read the docs on APIdock but they weren't terribly clear to me.

Comment: Checking in to see if you got this sorted.

Comment: No, I couldn't get your solution to work. I ended up implementing a very roundabout solution that entails directly accessing the join table to get the attributes. That works for what I need but it's not pretty.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. Would be curious to see your solution and it also might help a future info search. Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :post_users
    has_many :users, through: :post_users
  end

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :post_users
    has_many :posts, through: :post_users
  end

  class PostUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
  end
```

And then:

```
PostUser.where(post: current_user.posts.first).hide_twitter
```

Comment: Yes. I tried adding a wrapper method for `hide_twitter` to my `ContactPosts` model but I got the same error.